# Manually rotate a log file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logrotate

I have an Ubuntu web server running Nginx. I had never configured logfile rotation and have just discovered some multi-gigabyte monolithic log files.

I have configured log rotation now per [these tips](http://www.nginxtips.com/how-to-rotate-nginx-logs/). However, I'd rather not wait a week (my rotation period) before the rotation occurs.

Is there a way to force immediate rotation of either a specific file, or all files specified by the `logrotate` configuration?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Manually running `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/nginx` will forcefully rotate the logs configured in that file.